# Unable to convert String to Time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

Here is a query in which i want to convert a string which i formed after concatenating three fields into the time:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
  CONCAT(session_date," ",session_start_time," ",time_format),
  '%Y-%M-%e %h:%i %p'
) as u_date FROM sessions
```

`session_date` is a  date type field contains value `YYYY-MM-DD` and `session_start_time` is a varchar which hold string like this `HH:MM` and `time_format` is a field which is varchar as well contain values `AM` or `PM` So for example the string after concatenating becomes like this: `2012-10-03 12:16 PM`.

when i run this query i gets NULL result is there any syntax problem ? because if i remove the `STR_TO_DATE` the fields are concatenated without any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong date format:

```
%Y-%M-%e %h:%i %p
```

It should be:

```
%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p
```

Because

1. `%M` is for textual months, e.g. `"January"`
2. `%e` is for unpadded days, e.g. `"1"` instead of `"01"`.

Comment: Thanks mate yes i was giving the wrong format specifier :) Thanks alot once again mate..!!

Comment: @PHPSeeker You can use `SHOW WARNINGS;` on the command line if you want to know what was wrong.